# Where to define named parameter 'sliver'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So, I am creating a sliver based AppBar based on [this](https://youtu.be/1LGKZsff8bQ?t=500) example I found, and am facing the error `named parameter 'slivers' isn't defined`.

My code somewhat looks like this (I know I am probably putting the sliver in the wrong place, but any help in understanding the issue is appreciated).

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(
      CommunityMaterialIcons.plus,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
  slivers: <Widget>[ // *problematic sliver here*
    SliverAppBar(
      pinned: true,
      expandedHeight: 256.0,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: Text('po.'),
      ),
    ),
  ],
  body: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: tracks.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) { // the rest of the itembuilder continued here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed `slivers` field is not defined for `Scaffold`. Wrap your appbar and listview in `NestedScrollView` like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(
            Icons.plus_one,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        body: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                  pinned: true,
                  expandedHeight: 256.0,
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    title: Text('po.'),
                  ),
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              itemExtent: 20.0,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Text('entry $index');
              },
            )));
```

---

Here is fixed gist you provided:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData.dark(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final tracks = const [
    {'title': 'BCS Examination', 'subtitle': 'Something'},
    {'title': 'Dhaka University Admission'},
    {'title': 'Khulna University Admission'},
    {'title': 'Chottogram University Admission'},
    {'title': 'Bank Job Exam'},
    {'title': 'Bank Job Exam'}
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(
          Icons.info,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              expandedHeight: 256.0,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text('po.'),
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: tracks.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              var trackTitles = tracks[index];
              return Text(trackTitles['title']);
            }),
      ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked great! I faced a few small issues with the syntax, but managed to handle them. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the body you cold set a SliverList and set the child count as 0.
Something like:

```
SliverList(
  delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(<Widget>[]),
)
```

Normally I use it with a `CustomScrollView` but you could try.

Comment: Thank you. Will try this. But I have a question - if I use a SilverList like that, then wouldn't there be unnecessary processing (i.e. one check for each iteration)? Just trying to understand the logic here.

Comment: As I know, that will not make the iteration, that's why we set the Widget list, there is a way to make an iteration here too, but that's not the case now.